# Ubuntu Pound Reverse Proxy Load Balancing Based off active server load?

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have Pound installed on a loadbalancer.  It seems to work okay, except that it randomly assigns the backend server to forward the request to.  I've put 1 backend machine under so much load that it went into using swap, and I can't even ssh into it to test this scenareo.  I would like the loadbalancer to realize that the machine is overloaded, and send it to a different backend machine.  However it doesn't.  I've read the man page and it seems like the directive "DynScale 1" is what would monitor this, but it still redirects to the overloaded server.  I've also put in "HAport 22" to the backend figuring since I can't ssh in, neither could the loadbalancer and it would consider the backend server dead until it gets rid of the load and responds, but that didn't help either.

If anyone could help with this, I'd appreciate it.  My current config is below.

```
######################################################################
## global options:

User            "www-data"
Group           "www-data"
#RootJail       "/chroot/pound"

## Logging: (goes to syslog by default)
##      0       no logging
##      1       normal
##      2       extended
##      3       Apache-style (common log format)
LogLevel        3

## check backend every X secs:
Alive           5
DynScale        1

Client          1200
TimeOut         1500

# poundctl control socket
Control "/var/run/pound/poundctl.socket"


######################################################################
## listen, redirect and ... to:

## redirect all requests on port 80 to SSL
ListenHTTP
     Address 192.168.1.XX
     Port    80
     Service
          Redirect "https://xxx.com/"
     End
End

ListenHTTPS
     Address 192.168.1.XX
     Port    443
     Cert    "/files/www.xxx.com.pem"
     Service
           BackEnd
                  Address 192.168.1.1
                  Port 80
        HAport 22
           End
           BackEnd
                  Address 192.168.1.2
                  Port 80
        HAport 22
           End
     End
End
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `timeout` setting Pound waits 25 minutes for a response from the back-end. Set it to something lower during your tests, say the default of 15 secs.

Comment: Doesn't timeout referr to the amount of time when it sends a request to wait for the response?  I had this higher because I thought if a php script or something took more than 15 seconds to generate, it would just drop the connection.  I'll change it and let you know.

Comment: I changed it back to 15.  Now I get a "An internal server error occurred. Please try again later." after 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard very mixed opinions about the efficacy `DynScale`. We have chosen not to use it. What we do instead is set a `Priority` val for each `BackEnd` section. From the man page:

> Priority val
>
> > The priority of this back-end (between 1 and 9, 5 is default). Higher priority back-ends  will be used more often than lower priority ones, so you should define higher priorities for more capable servers.

Your new `ListenHTTPS` section should look something like this:

```
ListenHTTPS
     Address 192.168.1.XX
     Port    443
     Cert    "/files/www.xxx.com.pem"
     Service
           BackEnd
                  Address 192.168.1.1
                  Port 80
                  Priority 7
           End
           BackEnd
                  Address 192.168.1.2
                  Port 80
                  Priority 3
           End
     End
End
```

Try different values for the `Priority` on each `BackEnd` until you're happy with how it's distributing the load.

You should turn off `DynScale` while playing with `Priority`, otherwise Pound will attempt to adjust the values for you based on real usage.

Also, you should probably set `Alive` to something higher, like 30 seconds. If your servers are buried under more load than they can handle, you don't want Pound kicking it every 5 seconds to see if it's back up again.

Lastly, I agree with @Andrew. Your `Timeout` value should be much lower. Go with something modest, like 300 (5 minutes).

Comment: The machines are exactly the same specs, so priority should be the same for both. It's the real time usage I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't lower the timeout until certain reports are reworked to load faster. I also found that if the server does die, anyone trying to load a page has to wait the "Alive" time before their page times out and they get routed to a different machine. 30 seconds is just an unacceptable ammount of time for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending load traffic to one of the backend machines 'directly' (that is, without going through Pound), it will not be able to detect the load.

Pound will simply try port 80 of the backend (which will actually respond to the initial TCP handshake, SYN/ACK etc, but not much more than that) and will wait until the timeout you specified.

Try sending your load traffic through Pound, and experiment with the backend priorities and DynScale. Pound uses the number of open, ongoing connections to the backends to compute the load balancing.

Also, check the "poundctl" command to view some stats on the services/backends.